# Having trouble with my code overwriting itself and I am not sure why

Tags: c++

In the code below I can change the count amount newNodePtr->setCount(amount); to any value and it will stay changed. But I am trying to set it equal to one initially. And then if it occurs again I will go to the else statement and keep my linked list value at that location but change the count by +1.

```
template<class ItemType>
bool LinkedBag<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry)
{

    Node<ItemType> *newNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>();
    int amount = 0;
        if (getFrequencyOf(newEntry)<1)
        {
            newNodePtr->setItem(newEntry);
            newNodePtr->setNext(headPtr);
            itemCount++;
            amount++;
            newNodePtr->setCount(amount);
            headPtr = newNodePtr;

        }
        else
        {
            const int freqAmount = getFrequencyOf(newEntry);
            newNodePtr->setItem(newEntry);
            itemCount++;
            newNodePtr->setCount(freqAmount+1);
        }

    return true;
}  // end add
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your else block, you are setting the count on the newly created item. Not on the existing item in the list.

Comment: Thank you I can see that it doesn't change anything when I debug it. How would I go about changing the count on the old item?

Comment: Don't you have a function for retrieving an existing entry? `getFrequencyOf` must be able to.

Comment: So I believe I have figured out. In my list I need to be going to the headpointer in order to update the count.